# Is this termite ? Please help

Tags: termite

[ Update: I went to the back side of the walls, ie exterior. And updated a few more photos. Possibly the cause ]

[image][image]   Saw this small holes over my fireplace. And lot of sand like stuff on the ground.

When I put my ear against the wall, I think I hear something.

Photos attached.

Is this because of termites ?

Adding three more photos for more context. First show inside of house, second size, its next to the fireplace. And one to show the back of it, where we have brick walls.

[image]

[image]

[image]

====  The wood looks damaged, possibly from water ===

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Better call an exterminanator!

Comment: It may or may not be termites, but like ArchonOSX said, call in some help. Whatever it could be, you'd still want to stop it soon.

Comment: I have added three more pictures to give more context to the question. Thank you once again for taking a look.

Comment: Found damage to the wood under the roof. Please check new pictures.

Comment: I'll second the exterminator suggestion, but also suggest that it may be carpenter ants. What's your climate?

Comment: bay area california. Mostly warm. Very little rain.

Comment: Thank you once again. Yes, its termite. After inspection, he said this is the only place. The whole area is like 8ft by 5ft and spot treatment with 2 years warranty price quoted was $1300. Too high ? Ok ?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen bees do the same kind of damage, however those are small holes. I have also seen the smaller almost yellow jacket looking insects burrow into wood also, but I'm no entomologist so I couldn't tell you whathat they may be. I do know that spraying some wasp killer into those holes will most likely get rid of the problem if you don't wanna pay an exterminator. Those bees would burrow into the wooden beams on the outside porch. To eradicate them I'd plug all the holes but one and spray into the remaining exit, but they always come back. I've not seen them indoors though.
Edit* Just remembered another method of eradication - WD40 works just fine, and the tiny straw will fit right in those holes. Hope that helps.

Comment: I added 3 more photos. Hoping its not as bad as I initially thought.

Comment: Check the ground near the outside of your chimney for mudtubes. You could probably google image a termite mudtubes for reference, that may point you in the right direction of whats in there. I looked for a proper name for those small burrowing bees by the way, just known as carpenter bees. I've seen little green ones and others that look like large bumblebees.

Comment: Thanks Jeremiah. I looked near the chimney, found the wood needing a lot of attention. Please check the new photos I uploaded. Is that a mould ? Could not find mud tubes from the ground though.

Comment: If I were to guess that brown buildup in the corner is an old dirt dobber nest. Sometimes wood already has some type of larva (termites or whatever) in it if you get it from somewhere that doesn't treat it, and after the installation they eat their way out, and that cracked looking sawdust area coming out of the seams could be what that other area is. The cracking paint is definitely water related, maybe that wood wasn't sealed from where ever it came from. That's not too bad though, looks normal for the elemental damage most homes go through.

Comment: If it is termites, you definitely do not want to do what is suggested in this answer. Putting termites under attack can make them split off from the main colony and create a new one inside your house. I recommend calling in a professional to get a quote to be on the safe side.

Comment: Just to be clear, I mentioned spraying inside the holes to get rid of carpenter bees. Nothing about combating termites, as you're inferring.

Comment: I made no inference, just a comment based on what I know of termites to consult an expert if uncertain before acting on this advice since your answer did not 100% confirm it is a variety of carpenter bee.